# Make a lambda find the product of pairs of digits

Tags: python

**CODE**:

```
from functools import reduce

num = 2989

numSplit = [int(x) for x in str(num)]
# convert the number to a list with each digit separated

numProduct = reduce((lambda x,y: x*y), numSplit)
# uses reduce to multiply each number in order

print(numProduct)
```

**QUESTION**:

With NumProduct, I'm trying to find the separate products of `2*9`, `9*8`, and `8*9`.

I'm not sure how to modify the lambda to only find the product of pairs (or various other lengths) of digits in `[2,9,8,9]`. Need assistance with this. Tnx.

Comment: Use `itertools.combinations(numSplit, 2)`.

Answer (score 3):

`Reduce()` will reduce the entire iterable to a single value- this is not what you want. Instead, consider grouping the neighboring values into groups, and taking the product within each group.

```
num = 2989

numSplit = [int(x) for x in str(num)]
numProduct = [x * y for x, y in zip(numSplit, numSplit[1:])]
```

Here I `zip` the list `numSplit` with a slice of `numSplit` offset by one, to group each digit with its right neighbor. I then iterate over this, multiplying the two values. If one list is shorter than the other, `zip` truncates all the lists to the shortest length- which is what happens here, preventing an extra term at the end.

Result:

```
>>> numProduct
[18, 72, 72]
```

**Update**

If you want to support arbitrary sized groupings, use something like the following:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

num = 2989
size = 3

numSplit = [int(x) for x in str(num)]
numProduct = [reduce(mul, p) for p in zip(*(numSplit[x:] for x in range(size)))]
```

Result:

```
>>> numProduct
[144, 648]
```

Comment: Is there a way to increase the length of the grouping? Like grouping it by 298, and 989.

Comment: @user8507808 updated to handle arbitrary sized groupings

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to you can use reduce here.

```
from operator import mul
from functools import partial, reduce

p = partial(reduce, mul)

list(map(p, zip(numSplit, numSplit[1:])))

[18, 72, 72]

[reduce(mul, y) for y in zip(numSplit, numSplit[1:])]

[18, 72, 72]
```